# Issue with placement of the achievements menu drop down

Tags: bug, top-bar, page-rendering

I appear to have stumbled across a strange issue while doing a bunch of edits on Ask Ubuntu. Intermittently, the icon for the achievements menu drop down moves out of place. I can click on the icon in this new location and it will open the menu:

[image]

I have come across the issue multiple times during the period that I've been editing and I've only been editing on Ask Ubuntu so haven't replicated the issue on any other sites. The steps to reproduce this seem to be along the lines of:

- Using Google Chrome (I am using Chrome 32, I have not tested with other browsers)
- Open a number of posts to edit them (~10)
- Start editing posts
- At some point you'll come across a tab where the page looks like the above

Comment: Weird. Are you using Chrome on Ubuntu? Roughly how often does this occur for you? (I'm trying and failing to replicate it on OS X, although it seems like it could be tricky to hit.)

Comment: Chrome on Windows 8.1, after around opening 10 tabs (although I have had more than this open at various points during the night). I was also gaining reputation frequently (+2s) after the tab(s) had been opened.

Comment: From what you've described this doesn't seem likely to help, but just to rule it out for sure: do you have the browser at a non-default zoom level? Does resetting it (CTRL+0) have any effect?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the default zoom level